# Telerik mMVC master detail grid view for two unrelated models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, dom-events, master-detail

I need to display/present two different models in a master-detail grid.
One model(collection) is bound to master grid.It has a link in one of the column and is enabled/disabled based on condition. Simple.

What I need to do is upon clicking the link I should be able to populate the detail grid by calling another controller- action. I need the row information,to pass the row details/ model data to the controller-action to fetch the model for detail grid.How do I do this through Javascript/jQuery.

The detail model is not a collection.

Any other approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/detailsajax gives a great example on how to do this with AJAX.  I am assuming you are using the MVC Extensions by Telerik?

Comment: Thanks for your help Keith. I did it the similar way.